# getting access violation error while accessing allocated memory

Tags: c

I have allocated memory of 100 MB using malloc

```
block = (char *)malloc(sizeof(10485760));  // char *block is a global variable
```

and then I assigned value in block to some local variable say localblock

```
char *localblock = block;
```

when I tried to access location after 1 MB and copying string in that location im getting access violation error

```
int si = 1048576;

for (int i=0; i < si; ++i)
    ++localptr;
```

`strcpy(localblock,"random_string");` <--- im getting error here .please help me

Comment: `sizeof(10485760)`?? really? What do you think this does?

Comment: Also remove the C++ tag, this is C code - and in C you don't need to cast the return of `malloc` either

Comment: _"I have allocated memory of 100 MB using malloc ..."_  no you have not

Comment: There's a better way to advance a pointer by X elements instead of a loop: `localptr += si;`.

Comment: As @UnholySheep, C and C++ are very different languages. Only tag your question with one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
block = (char *)malloc(sizeof(10485760));
```

is allocating only sizeof(int) number of bytes, when you access memory beyond that its will end up accessing invalid memory and program might crash

Answer (score -1):

when you use `malloc` the allocation is not guaranteed.

`block = (char *)malloc(sizeof(10485760));`is *trying* to allocate space for *10485760* which is an `int` - meaning 4/8 bytes on 32/64-bit machine. `"random_string"` is longer then that, hence your error

Comment: `sizeof(10485760)` is the size needed for the litteral `10485760`